# how to buy a paid game on windows 8?

Tags: 8.0, parental-control

I have tried to download a paid game and it says I have to change the settings on my family but I don't know how to. I want to download this game but its a paid game and it pops up with a message saying that I can't download it as I need to go to windowsphone.com/family and change the my family settings but I don't know how to change it.